# Problemas com o SELECT RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, join, sql-select

Tenho duas tabelas, A e B. Na *Tabela A*, possuo uma coluna com nomes de máquinas (Cortadeira, Enfardadeira, Empacotadeira e Rebobinadeira) e na outra coluna algumas causas que as fizeram parar (Como Falta de Energia Elétrica, Troca de Bobina, etc).

Na *Tabela B*, possuo uma coluna com a listagem de todos os motivos possíveis (Na *Tabela A* estão apenas os que já ocorreram, cada linha mostra o nome de uma máquina e o motivo de sua parada.)

**Objetivo:**

Fazer com que o código me devolva o número de vezes que uma máquina específica ficou parada por cada motivo, retornando o valor `0` caso ela não tenha sido parada por aquele.

**Query atual:**

```
SELECT 
    B.TodosOsMotivos, 
    A.MotivosQueAconteceram, 
    A.Maquinas, 
    COUNT(A.MotivosQueAconteceram) as NumeroDeOcorrencias 
FROM A 
RIGHT join B on A.MotivosQueAconteceram = B.TodosOsMotivos 
WHERE A.Maquinas = 'Cortadeira' 
OR A.Maquinas IS NULL 
GROUP by MotivosQueAconteceram, Maquinas, B.TodosOsMotivos 
order by B.TodosOsMotivos
```

Dessa forma ela me diz quantas vezes a Cortadeira ficou parada por um motivo X e retorna `NULL` quando nenhuma máquina parou por algum motivo. O problema é que quando a CORTADEIRA não parou por um motivo Y mas OUTRA MÁQUINA parou, ele simplesmente não me retorna valor algum, quando eu precisava que me retornasse `0/NULL`. O que posso fazer para mudar isso?

**Tabelas:**

Essa é a *Tabela A* `pa_maquina` refere-se à coluna Maquinas da pergunta e `pa_motivos` refere-se à coluna `MotivosQueAconteceram`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a *Tabela B*, a coluna `descricao` refere-se à `TodosOsMotivos`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca a estrutura das tabelas por favor, está meio estranho isso, os dados não estao normalizados ?

Comment: Então, só pra entender. Você quer que apareça o número de vezes que a CORTADEIRA ficou parada e, caso a máquina seja diferente, que apareço 0? Não faz muito sentido, não é melhor mostrar a quantidade independente do tipo de máquina?

Comment: Sorack, preciso formar um gráfico para a cortadeira informando o índice de paradas dela para cada motivo. Posteriormente será feito individualmente para cada máquina. Acontece que quando um motivo aconteceu para outra máquina e não para aquela em que estou fazendo o gráfico, ele não retorna 0 vezes em que ela parou por aquele motivo, ele não retorna nada, e assim o php não inclui esse motivo no gráfico. Por isso eu precisaria o retorno de algum valor, mesmo que 0.

Comment: dvd, quando usou COUNT e não uso GROUP by dá erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você quer separar por motivos da tabela `B` e depois restringir pela tabela `A`, sugiro que faça um `subselect` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT b.TodosOsMotivos,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM A a
         WHERE a.MotivosQueAconteceram = b.TodosOsMotivos
           AND a.Maquinas = 'Cortadeira'
         GROUP BY a.MotivosQueAconteceram,
                  a.Maquinas) AS NumeroDeOcorrencias
  FROM B b
```

Assim todos os motivos serão listados e, dentro de cada um, o número de ocorrências da tabela `A` para a coluna `Maquinas` com valor de `Cortadeira` será contado corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro o seguinte SELECT:

```
SELECT
    B.Maquina,
    B.Motivo,
    SUM(B.Total)
FROM
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN B.[descricao] = A.[pa_motivo]
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END AS 'Total',
        A.[pa_maquina] AS 'Maquina',
        B.[descricao] AS 'Motivo'
    FROM
        #pa_maquina A, #pa_motivos B) B
GROUP BY
    B.Maquina,
    B.Motivo
ORDER BY
    B.Maquina,
    B.Motivo
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de solução:

Você faz uma query que retorne a união de todas as combinações de máquina e motivo com quantidade zero (`CROSS JOIN`) e todas a as combinações de máquina e motivo que possuem alguma alguma parada(`INNER JOIN`) e dessa query você retorná os registros com a quantidade maior e pode filtrar pela máquina que quiser.

Exemplo online: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1c1cb/90)

```
SELECT Nome
  , Motivo
  , MAX(Quantidade) AS 'Quantidade de paradas'
FROM 
  (SELECT
    pa_maquina.pa_maquina AS Nome
    , pa_motivo.Descricao AS Motivo
    , 0 AS Quantidade
  FROM pa_maquina
  CROSS JOIN pa_motivo
  UNION
  SELECT
    pa_maquina.pa_maquina AS Nome
    , pa_motivo.Descricao AS Motivo
    , COUNT(pa_motivo.id) AS Quantidade
  FROM pa_maquina
  JOIN pa_motivo 
    ON pa_motivo.id = pa_maquina.pa_motivo
  GROUP BY Nome, Motivo
) AS Uniao
WHERE Nome = 'Cortadeira'
GROUP BY Nome, Motivo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]